# Confused to use OR, str_replace, array or what?

Tags: php, html, url

I have a code that finds the words `Alabama` and `Michigan` inside `$l` and return the if condition:

```
<?php if (trim($l) == "Alabama" || trim($l) == "Michigan"): ?>
   <a href="http://www.example.com/"><?= $l ?></a>
 <?php else: ?>
   <a href="http://www.example.com/"></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Sometimes I don't have `Alabama` and `Michigan` inside `$l` but I have `AL` and `MI` that are related to `Alabama` and `Michigan` and in that case I want replace `AL` and `MI` with `Alabama` and `Michigan`. If I want to do it inside the code above to write a clean and short code, how should I do it? I have a lot more words to match and associate them together so please give me a clean code.

Comment: `so please give me a clean code` - this is not how SO works. We do not write your code for you. You will have to write it yourself and if it doesn't work, then you can ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use  a  regexp  as

```
  if(preg_match('(Michigan|Alaska|MI|AL)', $l) === 1) {

    ........

   }
```

in Your case

```
<?php if (preg_match('(Michigan|Alaska|MI|AL)', $l) === 1): ?>
   <a href="http://www.example.com/"><?= $l ?></a>
 <?php else: ?>
   <a href="http://www.example.com/"></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or for replace

```
<?php 
  $short = ["MI", "AL"];
  $long   = ["Michigan", "Alaska"];

  $newl = str_replace($short, $long, $l);
?>
<?php if (preg_match('(Michigan|Alaska)', $newl) === 1): ?>

   <a href="http://www.example.com/"><?= $newl ?></a>
 <?php else: ?>
   <a href="http://www.example.com/"></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You miss the part where the user wants to replace `AL` by `Alabama` for example.

Comment: Let's say I have 'Montgomery,-AL' in '$l' then your code should returns 'Alabama' for '$l'

Comment: @AnwarNairi   ... the replace is un useful  .. the regexp can check for MI an AL directly  ,, without replacing  .. .. to me the use of regexp  without replace seems a lot of  more clear and clean

Comment: @Smith  i don't understand .. the difficult part for you is the replace of the string .. ???  let me know

Comment: Yes, exactly, replacing is the issue

Comment: that's very close, but please update your answer to replace 'Alabama' with whole 'Montgomery,-AL' not just with 'AL'

Comment: this is not a coding service  .. and looking to  your original question  .,. there is not refer  to you last comments  ... ..in your OP you tell just about changin the state CODE with the state name  ..not others ..  you should try yourself to buil the string you need .. non ask  to other to write code for you ..

Comment: ok, ill accept your abswer and will ask this question in another time. thanks